# Pick Out Email From a Row

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have over 100k rows similar to:

```
Joe | 123 | email@domain.com 
Bob | 456
Ben | 567 | Denver | email@email.com
```

The emails could be at any point/cell in that row and some cells have @ in them.

How could I get the following output:

```
Joe | email@domain.com 
Bob | 
Ben | email@email.com
```

or maybe just tag the email address onto the end of the row and then hide the other columns?

I've tried various bits and pieces but am getting nowhere fast.

Comment: Are the email addresses always in the last column of a given row?

Answer (score 2):

Now that I know you can have it in every column, Add a column left of column A. In your example you then have B1="Joe", etc.

Then put this formula in A1:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(A1,0,SUM(IFERROR(IF(FIND("@",$B1:$O1)>0,1,0),0)*COLUMN($B1:$O1))-1),"")
```

Adjust the range $B1:$O1 to match your needs. I suggest you make it as tight as possible because array formulas are resource-intensive.

========================

If the email addresses were always in the last column of a given row, and if there weren't any blanks in the row until the last value, you could just do that:

First, Add a column left of column A. In your example you then have B1="Joe", etc.

Then, put this formula in cell A1

```
=OFFSET(A1,0,COUNTA($B1:$XFD1))
```

and drag and drop it on all your rows. (I'm using Excel 2010, hence XFD in the above formula. Adjust as you see fit, just make sure you use a range that covers the maximum number of columns for your dataset)

Comment: Unfortunately the emails could be at any point/cell in that row

Comment: See my update with Array formula. That being said, it's pretty twisted and verging on the limit where VBA makes more sense...

Comment: You could just use Regex. Plenty of resources on this site.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of fun really. 
Embolden the names and for the rest Replace All `@` without formatting with `@` and Font style Bold. Copy into Word, Select All, Find what: `*` with Font Not Bold, Use wildcards and replace with nothing. Copy back into Excel and Go To Special, Blanks. Right click on one of selection and Delete…, Shift cells left.

Comment: The problem is that some cells have @ in them - and there's over 100k rows :-(

Comment: I was thinking about regex but never usd it in excel before